# Character inside square brackets not read in JAVA BufferedReader

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have written the following code to check for regular expression.The following is the code snippet.

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String regEx =br.readLine();
    System.out.println("-->");
    System.out.print(regEx);
    System.out.println("-->");
```

I am getting the following output in IntelliJ Run Window

```
    \d[.]\d
    -->
    \d[]\d-->

    \d\d\d[a-z]\d\d\d
    \d\d\d[-z]\d\d\d-->
```

Why is the character inside square brackets not shown

Comment: I do not have IntelliJ, but it works fine in command line (1.8.0_131, 64-bit, Windows). Consider testing it too, then you may want to report a bug (somewhere at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/reporting-issues-and-sharing-your-feedback.html perhaps)

Comment: What is your keyboard layout? Do you need to use AltGr key to type a square bracket? Are you using IntelliJ IDEA with Jetbrains custom JRE (shipped with IDE), or a separate installation of Java?

Answer (score 0):

probably it is intellij idea issue

in my version 2016.3 CE all works fine

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java 
\d[.]\d
-->
\d[.]\d-->

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell exactly from the available information, but it seems clear the code is alright, and the issue lies with your IDE... which makes this issue not really about programming, and likely off-topic.

I'm guessing the IDE gets confused when you type whatever is needed to enter an opening square bracket, depending on your keyboard layout. Problem would not be with `BufferedReader` but rather how the IDE handles keyboard input in that view, and how it passes that input to the stdin stream (`System.in`) of your program.

To verify that, can you try typing a regex pattern with square brackets *outside of the IDE*, then *copy-paste the string* into IntelliJ. Does it work better, or the same?

In case you would be using a keymap that requires AltGr to type an opening bracket (Croatian, French...), check out [this page](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206189269-Unable-to-write-square-or-curly-brackets-in-IntelliJ-IDEA-CE-while-using-Croatian-keymap-), and the suggested fix:

> Please try adding `actionSystem.force.alt.gr=true` to `bin/idea.properties` and restart the IDE